# Return to sum of powers question.

Tags: calculus, diophantine-equations

Previously I had asked a question about a Diophantine equation [linked here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/864739/has-anyone-solved-this-general-diophantine-equation).

I have come back to think about this question but in a different manner.

So here is the set up:

Let A and $a_i$ be integers such that $A \ge a_i \ge 0$ for every i, and A is non-zero.

The sum in question now is,

$\sum_{i=1}^ka_i^k=A^k$

Dividing by A^k,

$\sum_{i=1}^k({a_i\over A})^k=1$

Now we ask for what sequences of $a_i$ is this true for $k \ge 3$?

What if take the lim of this?

$\lim_{k \to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^k({a_i\over A})^k $ and ask if it converges to 1?

Yes, I know that we can rewrite the ${a_i \over A}$ as $b_i$ to make the sum: $\sum_{i=1}^kb_i^k=1$, and the limit $\lim_{k \to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^kb_i^k $, but I would rather not lose any information pertaining to the sequence.

My question is what now? Have I made this too general to solve, prove, or this disprove? Has anyone else made this approach? If I am close what tools am I going to need to show either? What restrictions might be better to change?

I had thought about this approach after thinking about the connection between compounding interest and continual interest.

Answer (score 1):

For particular $k$ you might get particular integer solutions.  It would only make sense to take a limit if you had a family of solutions parametrized by $k$, where
$a_i = f(i,k)$ for some function $f$ and $A = A(k)$.  I don't know if there are
such families of solutions

EDIT: (other that the trivial $A^k + 0^k + \ldots + 0^k = A^k$).